# Fedex PHP soap api with multiple service types?

Tags: php, soap, opencart, fedex

i am using fedex soap api for retrieving shipping rates, but in ServiceType i am able to send only one type i.e. PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, how can i send multiple Services in one request like GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY, INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT,STANDARD_OVERNIGHT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can omit the `$request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType']` from the request and FedEx will return all available shipping methods. You'll then need to loop through the `$response->RateReplyDetails` array to extract each shipping method.

Keep in mind that the package type i.e. `$request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType']` will limit the shipping methods returned. The value `YOUR_PACKAGING` should return all of the methods, while others such as `FEDEX_BOX` only returns overnight and 2 day options (at least for me). However this may sometimes affect the price too.

Comment: Hi
I am having the same issue regarding service types but if I don't send service type in request I get an error in response saying "Service not allowed". Can someone explain to me how can I get rates for all service types?

Comment: I got it. There is ServiceTypeSpecified property on RequestedShipment that needs to be set to false in order to omit ServiceType property.

Comment: guys, did you find anything?